# Is there a verb for unintellectual or stupid?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering if the word "unintellectualize" or "De-intellectualize" is a word. Basically a word such as "belittles" but more specific to intellectual qualities of a certain group of people or a person.

I'm writing an essay about how institutions often create narratives that certain minority groups are "stupid" to justify their marginalization. I need a verb for this:

> The government often "deintellectualizes" (I need a replacement word for this because I don't think it's a real word) Indigenous women by using slang during communication with them to indicate their intellectual inferiority.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144982/discussion-on-question-by-hanna-is-there-a-verb-for-unintellectual-or-stupid); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot always rely on single words to express exactly what we are trying to say.  You seem to be trying to express the way in which people refer to them condescendingly as if they lacked the intelligence to speak for themselves or understand for themselves the challenges they face.  So say what you want to say using as many words as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Demean:  to cause a severe loss in the dignity of and respect for someone or something.

Denigrate:  to critize unfairly, disparage. 'there is a tendency to denigrate the poor'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think '[infantilise](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/infantilize)' might be as close as you can get:

> to treat or regard as infantile or immature.

Perceived naivety can be considered a product of intellectual underdevelopment.
A good example of this, taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infantilization#Older_adults), is talking to elderly people "*as if they were a child incapable of understanding complex topics*".

---

I would also definitely change the rest of your sentence:

> [..] during communication with them to indicate their intellectual inferiority.

This reads as if their "intellectual inferiority" is a fact that is merely *exposed* by the government. I recommend changing 'indicate' to 'implicate', or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *belittle*, as in

> The government often belittles indigenous women by
> using slang during communication with them to indicate their
> intellectual inferiority.

OED, under the headword *belittle*, gives us

> *Originally U.S.*
>
> **1. a**. *transitive*. To reduce in size, make small. Now with overtones
> of, and difficult to distinguish from, sense 2.

and, for sense 2

> **2.** *transitive*. To dismiss the importance of, depreciate.

Answer (score 0):

**talk down (to)**

> *verb*
> as in to *patronize*
> to assume or treat with an air of superiority
>
> > just because I don't have extensive experience in the field is no
> > reason to *talk down to* me as if I were a child
>
> [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/talk%20down%20(to))

It's usually best to be as specific as possible. Longer words aren't necessarily better, and a verb can be more than one word.